# Minhag to not share a photo of a newborn

Tags: pregnancy-birth

Is there anything mentioning about either sharing photos of a newborn child or specifically not sharing photos of a newborn?
(or maybe not sharing pictures before the bris?)

Comment: There is no such ancient minhag (since photographs were only invented pretty recently)

Comment: @DoubleAA It does not need to be "ancient". (The prohibition against using electricity on shabbos isn't ancient either lol)

Comment: building and writing and nolad (or whatever rubric you think electricity falls into) are indeed ancient lol

Comment: Drawing pictures of people is ancient as well lol.

Comment: Perhaps it is connected to ayin hara much like tying red ribbon by the crib https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/327382?lang=bi